# Create a treelike structure with a variable generation amount

Tags: java

I have 4 two dimensional numbers: (1,0), (0,1), (0,-1), (-1,1). I would like to build a treelike structure with n generations and get a result for every single path. For n = 2, the result for one of the 4^n= 16 paths would be (1,0) + (0,1) = (1,1) for example.

I would know how to achieve that with a set amount of generations, but have no idea how to create a treelike structure like that with a variable amount of generations. I would usually just go through a for-loop for each generation, but i don´t know how to add n amount of for-loops automatically for n generations.

Would be nice if someone could help me out here. (I´m using java).

Edit: im only searching for paths with the result (0, n), so if anyone knows a more efficient algorithmn than the one mentioned, it would be also pretty nice to hear them

Comment: `but i don´t know how to add n amount of for-loops` - nested loop maybe?

Comment: You make a recursive function, that traverses a tree and if it encounters a leaf it adds 4 children to it. And you call it N times on your root node with (0,0). Each node of a tree has 4 children and a field that stores either one of the `Pair(int,int)` or the summ of those pairs up to this node.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your edit: You might use some sort of list, at the creation of a node check if its value satisfies your condition and if so, add it to the list. (The whole node, not just the value).
If you double- link your tree (so if the children have a pointer to the parent) you can traverse the tree in oposite direction up to the root.
That gives you the path, you only have to turn it upside down.

You could use a proper tree structure, where every node has 4 childs 1 parent, a value and a depth. So to calculate the values of new children of a certain node you would simply add those vektors to the current value, their depth would of course be one more than the one of their parents. To populate the tree I would recommend recursive method calls, with a breaking condition depending on the depth.

But I am not entirely sure what it is you want to achieve.